# Creating a pandas dataframe from dict of lists of columns which have True

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I would like to take a dictionary of `'item': [list_of_True_column_labels]` that looks like this:

```
pre_df  = {'item1':['a','b','c'], 'item2':['c','d'], 'item3':['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'item4':['e']}
```

and turn it into a pandas dataframe of `bool` like this:

```
index   A      B      C      D      E
item1  True   True   True   False  False
item2  False  False  True   True   False
item3  True   False  True   True   True
item4  False  False  False  False  True
```

1) I've tried this (from StackOverflow):

```
pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in pre_df.items()]))
```

but that gives me an incorrect dataframe:

```
    item1 item2 item3 item4
0     a     c     a     e
1     b     d     c   NaN
2     c   NaN     d   NaN
3   NaN   NaN     e   NaN
```

2) using `pd.melt()` doesn't seem to be the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the dictionary and convert each value to a Series object with the original list as the index and value to be `True`, and then call the `DataFrame.from_dict()` method. This gives a transposed version of your desired output. Transpose the result and fill NaN with `False` gives what you need:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: pd.Series(True, v) for k, v in pre_df.items()}).T.fillna(False)
```

[image]